# Display row/column data for csv with max value in another column, same row (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I'm trying to make a script that sorts column 2 for highest value, prints said value, and prints column 3 for every row matching this value. Here's an example of unsorted csv:

```
Argentina,4.6,2016,some data
Argentina,4.2,2018,some data
Argentina,4.6,1998,some data
Argentina,4.5,2001,some data
```

Desired output would be:

```
4.6
2016
1998
```

Here's what I've got so far, but I'm feeling unsure if I'm going about it correctly:

```
grep  "$2*" "$1"> new.csv

sort -t, -k2,2nr new.csv > new2.csv

cut -f3 -d"," new2.csv
```

Wherein $2 is the name of country in first column and $1 is the filename. While it sorts the values in the 2nd column just fine, I'd like to show the years for only the rows with max value in column 2. This route just prints the years for all of the rows, and I understand why that's happening, but not sure the best course to get the intended result from there. What are some ways to go about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: does your data file actually have a space after the commas and if so do you need that (leading) space removed from the final result?

Comment: nope there's no leading space, that was just force of habit to make it less cramped looking haha

Comment: Oh thank you! I can't believe I overlooked that

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that:

```
declare maxvalue_found=no
declare maxvalue=''
while read -r line; do
  IFS=',' read -r <<< "$line" country value year data

  if [[ "${maxvalue_found}" == no ]]; then
    echo "$value"
    maxvalue="${value}"
    maxvalue_found=yes
  fi
  if [[ "${value}" == "${maxvalue}" ]]; then
    echo "$year"
  fi
done < new2.csv
```

`new2.csv` is your sorted file: we simply read it line by line, then read said line by splitting using ',' (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting):

- The first value should be the highest due to sort.
- The next value must be tested because you want only those that matches.
- The year are print in same order than in new2.csv

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- comma only shows up as a field delimiter (ie, comma is not part of any data)
- no sorting requirement has been defined for the final result

---

One `awk` idea requiring 2 passes through the unsorted file:

```
awk -F, '                                     # set input field delimiter as comma
FNR==NR { max=($2>max ? $2 : max); next}      # 1st pass of file (all rows): keep track of max value from field #2
FNR==1  { print max }                         # 2nd pass of file (1st row ): print max
$2==max { print $3 }                          # 2nd pass of file (all rows): if field #2 matches "max" then print field #3
' unsorted.csv unsorted.csv
```

This generates:

```
4.6
2016
1998
```

---

Another `GNU awk` idea that requires a single pass through the unsorted file:

```
awk -F, '                                     # set input field delimiter as comma
    { arr[$2][$3]                             # save fields #2 and #3 as indices in array "arr[]"
      max = ( $2 > max ? $2 : max)            # keep track of max value from field #2
    }
END { print max                               # after file has been processed ... print max and then ...
      for (i in arr[max])                     # loop through indices of 2nd dimension where 1st dimension == max
          print i                             # print 2nd dimension index (ie, field #3)
    }
' unsorted.csv
```

This generates:

```
4.6
1998
2016
```

**NOTES:**

- `GNU awk` required for arrays of arrays (ie, multidimensional arrays)
- while field #3 appeara to be sorted this is not guaranteed unless we modify the code to explicitly sort the 2nd dimension of the array

Answer (score 1):

A single pass awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{                    
    if($2>=m||m=="") {          
        b= ($2==m?b:$2) ORS $3   # b is the record buffer 
        m=$2                     # m holds the maximum of $2 so far
    } 
}
END {
    print b
}' file
```

Output:

```
4.6
2016
1998
```

Comment: you can make this one even more concise :::: from ::::::: if($2>=m||m==""):::::::::to simply ::::::::::::::::::::::: ::: if ( m <= $2 ) :::: reason being - if value of "m" is already the empty null string, then your compare will always evaluate to true,  even if $2 itself is also empty, and also regardless of what data type $2 currently possesses. "less than empty string" may have some meaning in a new age paradigm like python slices, but since awk doesn't have that complication, it makes life a lot simpler.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Yes, unless all the values are negative in which case my script would output nothing.

Comment: @JB : actually i realized we're both wrong if it's negative : jot - -9999999999 -1 1234 | mawk2 'BEGIN { srand()+srand() }{ printf("1 %s %s\n",$0,1900+int(122*rand())) }' | mawk '1;1;1;1' | shuf  | mawk '{ if($2>=m || m=="") {  b= ($2==m?b:$2) ORS $3 } } END { print b }'
-5146238695
1982 :::::::::  i intentionally made 4 duplicated copies of every combo, so the year should print 4 times - it prints once. What's worse : Each run generates a diff value for which negative value it took on

Comment: @JB : you can see what works with which ::::::; <<< '=-9888.'  mawk 'function p() { print ($1 "" <= $2),($1<$2),(+$1<$2),($1<+$2),"=======",("" $1 < $2), ($1 < "" $2), (+$1 <= +$2),($1==$2) } { print $0; p(); $1=int($2); p() }' FS='[= \t]+'
=-9888.
1 1 0 1 ======= 1 1 0 0 (\n)
1 0 0 0 ======= 1 1 1 1

Answer (score 0):

How about single-pass in `awk` instead of multi-pass ? I've generated this synthetic version of the file, plus randomizing some data, to create a 6.24 mn row version of it :

**INPUT**

```
out9:  177MiB 0:00:01 [ 105MiB/s] [ 105MiB/s] [ <=> ]

rows = 6243584. | UTF8 chars = 186289540. | bytes = 186289540.
```

**CODE**

- *default value initialized to gigantically negative value of*
  `-2^512`, *or more elegantly*, `-4^4^4`, *to ensure it'll always take on the value on row 1

  if you really want to play it safe, then make it something very close to* `negative infinity` :

  ```
   e.g. -(3+4+1)^341, -16^255, -256^127, or -1024^102
  ```

=

```
   {m,g}awk '

   BEGIN {
     1     _= -(_^= __= _+= _^= FS= OFS = ",")^_^_
     1   ___= split("",____)
    }

    # Rule(s)

6243584  +_ <= +$__ { # 2992

  2992              __= $(NF = ++__)
  2992      if ((+_)< +$--NF) {
     7               _=  $NF
     7             ___= split("",____)
            }
  2992      ____[++___]=__
  2992               __=NF
    }
    END {
     1      print _
  2984      for (__^=_<_; __<=___; __++) {
  2984          print ____[__]
            }
    }
```

**OUTPUT** (*column 3 printed exactly in input row order*)
.

```
53.6  1834  1999  1866  1938  1886  1973  1968  1921  1984  1957  1891  1864  1992
1998  1853  1950  1985  1962  2018  1897  1979  2020  1954  1995  1980  1900  1997
1856  1975  1851  1853  1988  1897  1973  1875  1917  1861  1912  1912  1954  1871
1952  1877  2003  1886  1863  1899  1897  1853  2013  1956  1965  1854  1873  1915
1983  1961  1965  1979  1919  1970  1946  1843  1856  1954  1965  1831  1926  1964

1994  1969  1831  1945  1942  1971  1988  1879  1998  1986  1844  1846  1994  1894
2008  1851  1877  1979  1970  1852  1942  1889  1986  2013  1905  1932  2021  1944
1866  1892  1940  1989  1907  1982  2016  1966  1975  1831  1851  2003  1980  1963
1869  1983  1972  2013  1972  1948  1843  1928  1959  1911  1844  1920  1943  1864
1985  1978  1855  1986  1975  1880  2001  1914  1877  1900  1964  1995  1992  1968

1868  1974  2012  1827  1849  1849  1992  1942  1884  1876  2021  1866  1977  1857
1866  1937  1920  1983  1915  1887  1890  1852  1871  1972  1903  1944  1943  1957
1844  1932  1854  1890  1891  1866  1923  1924  1941  1845  1907  2019  

(further rows truncated for readability)
```